# Como puedo hacer para no cambiar el valor de una variable en AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Necesito crear una variable que guarde el estado de la `función` que ejecuto en el $interval llamada `$scope.getSignatureCallStatus();` esa función ejecuta una petición que guarda en una variable `$scope.callStatus = res.data;` el estado...
son 3 estados:

```
{
    success
    fail
    hangup
}
```

Entonces si la variable `$scope.callStatus = 'success'` que me guarde en una variable nueva ese valor o que sea `TRUE`, algo asi como `$scope.callStatusSucces = $scope.callStatus == 'success'`, pero como esta en un interval el valor cambia dinamicamente, entonces quiero que la variable nueva no cambie el valor...

```
$scope.promise = $interval(function() {
    $scope.getSignatureCallStatus();
    $scope.showStatus = true;
}, 2500);
```

Esta es la función `$scope.getSignatureCallStatus();`

```
$scope.getSignatureCallStatus = function() {
        $http.get('url', {
            params: {
                param: param
            }
        }).then(function(res){
            $scope.callStatus = res.data;
        });
    };
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, si `$scope.callStatus === 'fail'` entonces no tiene nada que puedas filtrar para poblar `$scope.callStatusFail`. `$filter("filter")` filtra arreglos: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @Klaimmore Edite mi pregunta con una nueva, por favor revisala

Comment: Publica el codigo de `getSignatureCallStatus` para saber como guardas el valor en `$scope.callStatus` (porque, es ahi donde se settea, no?). Ahi es donde se podria poner un acondicion o de alguna forma verificar si el estado es `success`

Comment: @Lealceldeiro ya lo agregue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por tu pregunta entiendo que solo quieres saber cuando `$scope.callStatus` ha sido 'success' alguna vez. En este caso puedes hacer lo mismo que planteabas en la pregunta: declarar una variable `$scope.callStatusSucces` (nombre propuesto por ti en la pregunta) y asignarle true cuando `$scope.callStatus == 'success'`.

La funcion quedaria asi:

```
$scope.getSignatureCallStatus = function() {
    $http.get('url', {
        params: {
            param: param
        }
    }).then(function(res){
        $scope.callStatus = res.data;
        if (!$scope.callStatusSucces) { // si `$scope.callStatusSucces` no ha sido setteado o `$scope.callStatus` nunca ha sido 'success'
            $scope.callStatusSucces = $scope.callStatus == 'success'
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: entonces serian 3 if para guardar los 3 estados?

Comment: Entendí que solo querias saber si habia habido algun `success`. Exactamente que información deseas almacenar en variables? El último estado que llegó, si ha llegado cada uno de los estados en determinado momento... otra opción?

Comment: Recuerda que cada vez que se ejecute la llamada en el interval, el valor puede cambiar

Comment: si tienes razon, enrealidad hay mas estados pero con esto me basta, gracias por tu ayuda :)